# karaf individual dependencies error

Tags: java, apache-karaf

My problem is I simply download karaf 2.3.11 from

http://karaf.apache.org/index/community/download.html#Karaf2.3.11

for windows.

when I run karaf and type la command on karaf shell it will show some dependencies blueprint are created but some are failure.

Any help appriciated.

Comment: issue is with java8. It runs ok with java7

Comment: Try to use 3.x and check it will be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java8 will be supported starting from Karaf 2.4.0. and  3.0.2

Karaf 2.3.1 does not support Java8 (and will never support it).

Comment: what about 4.0.1. Does this version support java 8 ??

Comment: yes it will support both 7 / 8. if you satisfied accept the answer

Comment: It is very helpful for me. But because of my reputation i cannot make a mark for you.